# Making the CMAKE path available to another software

Tags: cmake, makefile, sundials

I am trying to install a software package called kinsol, a non-linear equation solver, through ccmake as instructed in its documentation. The package requires a cmake version 3.12 or higher. So, I installed 3.17.3. Now, the problem is that my kinsol installation process is not able to locate ccmake and hence gives the message "ccmake ../kinsol-6.2.0
The program 'ccmake' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install cmake-curses-gui". But using the aforementioned command installs the version 3.5, which again fails in the task due to the version requirement of kinsol. I had come across a similar question in this forum and so I followed the workarounds suggested there as in putting the installation path of cmake in the .bashrc file still without any success. Does anyone know how to make the path of cmake known to the software?

Thanks,
DP

Comment: Is kinsol open source? What steps did you follow to install CMake? What commands did you run _exactly_?

Comment: Why are you trying to run `ccmake`?  Why not just run `cmake` (without the curses interface)?  If you want to run `ccmake` then you'll have to install that.  As Alex says, you say "So, I installed 3.17.3" but you give us not a single clue how you went about doing that.  Since `apt` is going to install an older version, you must have used some other method to install version 3.17.

Comment: Yes it is open source. For CMake installation, I downloaded the zip file "cmake-3.17.3.tar.gz" from its website. Then,I went inside its extracted folder and entered "sudo ./bootstrap" in the terminal followed by "make" and "make install". The installation went fine. The reason for preference towards ccmake is to comply with the instructions given in the documentation. Nothing more to it.

Comment: Very likely it didn't create the curses interface to `cmake`, probably because you don't have the proper curses development libraries installed.  If you go back and look at the output of the build commands you invoked, you'll probably notice some text in there somewhere saying something to that effect.  But, you don't need it anyway.  You can just run `cmake`.  `ccmake` just gives a fancy front-end for configuring the software.

Comment: I need to configure the software since it has disabled a few of the things I am looking for.

Comment: You can configure things via the `cmake` command line, by adding appropriate `-D...=ON` or `-D...=OFF` options.  But, if you want to use `ccmake` you'll have to investigate the output of the cmake build you performed and figure out why `ccmake` was not created.  That is, assuming `cmake --version` shows you the right version info.

Comment: I was able to configure the installation using cmake. Thanks